# Setting colors in theme.json changes default font size and family in backend

Tags: themes, block-editor, theme.json

I have a basic theme.json with an array or colors that creates a working colour palette.

The text in the backend page I am editing is set to 'default' but when I use the theme.json it goes from sans to a serif font.

I have tried adding fontfamiles to theme.json but nothing seems to effect the default backend text rendering.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.